# how to use metapost newinternal variable

Tags: metapost

I am trying to convert the statement

```
drawarrow (0,0)--(100,100) dashed evenly withcolor green;
```

to

```
newinternal string varA ; 
varA := "dashed evenly withcolor green" ; 
drawarrow (0,0)--(100,100) varA ;
```

but it fails in the line of `drawarrow`. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Or you could just do `drawoptions(dashed evenly withcolor green);` then draw your arrow(s), then set things back to normal with `drawoptions()`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`dashed evenly withcolor green` is not a string, but a list of tokens. You want

```
def varA = dashed evenly withcolor green enddef;
```

so a macro. Full example

```
def varA = dashed evenly withcolor green enddef;

beginfig(1);
drawarrow (0,0)--(100,100) varA ;
endfig;
end.
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you and thank you.

Comment: @user1389406 If you like this answer and it was helpful, please consider upvoting (by clicking on the arrows next to the score) and/or marking it as the accepted answer (by clicking on the checkmark ✓).

Comment: question. how to "by clicking on the arrow next to the score"  ?

Answer (score 4):

Instead of `def`, you can also apply `scantokens` which converts from string to tokens. Just ensure your string is MetaPost sensible code:

```
newinternal string varA ; 
varA := "dashed evenly withcolor green"; 
drawarrow (0,0)--(100,100) scantokens(varA);
```

You're now able to store a list of strings to be later tokenized, but it's not that useful unless you really need chunks of MetaPost as strings. Another example:

```
string Vars[]; 
Vars[1] := "dashed evenly withcolor green"; 
Vars[2] := "dashed evenly withcolor red"; 
drawarrow (0,0)--( 100, 100) scantokens(Vars[1]);
drawarrow (0,0)--(-100,-100) scantokens(Vars[2]);
```

I wouldn't actually recommend it as you might be caught by some expansion issues (as @egreg says, MetaPost, like TeX, works with tokens and thus faces the same issues), but it's fine for the simplest cases.

Answer (score 1):

Plain Metapost already provides a mechanism to apply the same set of drawing options to a sequence of drawing commands.  So another way to achieve what (I think) you are trying to do, would be as follows

```
prologues := 3;
outputtemplate := "%j%c.eps";
defaultfont := "phvr8r";
beginfig(1);

    drawoptions(dashed evenly withcolor 1/2 green);
    drawarrow origin -- (100, 100);
    label.urt("Green but not dashed", (100, 100));

    drawoptions(withcolor 2/3 red);
    drawarrow origin -- 84 dir 72;
    drawarrow origin -- 74 dir 82;

    drawoptions(); % back to default colors and style
    drawarrow origin -- 84 dir 13;

endfig;
end.
```

Compile this with `mpost` to get

[image]

### Notes

- drawing options that you set with `drawoptions` apply to all subsequent
  `draw`, `fill`, or `label` commands until you call `drawoptions` again.
- notice that the colour applies to both labels and drawing, but the dashes are only applied to the drawn arrow.
- `drawoptions` resets *all* the options, so the second one changes the colour explicitly, but also implicitly resets the line style.
- hence the call `drawoptions();` will reset everything to defaults
- in plain MP, the `beginfig` macro automatically calls `drawoptions()` to reset everything for you at the start of each figure.